# How can QML TreeView delegate determine if it is selected

Tags: delegates, qml, treeview

I am using a delegate in a QML TreeView (QQC2), and when showing each item (one per delegate) I want to change the background color if the current item is selected.

In QQC1 there was a 'selected' property available within the delegate.  But in QQC2 that is gone.  I can access 'currentModelIndex" which contains the model index of the currently selected item, but not sure what to do with that.

How can I tell *in the delegate* if THIS item model index matches the selected model index?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
selected: (row == TreeView.view.currentIndex.row) && (column == TreeView.view.currentIndex.column)
```

Comment: The problem appears to be that TreeView.view.currentIndex.row never changes when a selection is made (and is always zero or null, or something that doesn't match 'row')

Comment: I figured it out with a slight change to your code: use mytreeviewid.view.currentIndex.* and then it works :)  If you want to make update/clarification to your code I'll mark accepted.  Also, I managed to figure out what your code does but a brief explanation may help others.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear. Make sure you are using the latest repo as there have been some bug fixes going into `TreeView` lately. Honestly I don't think I will be answering any more of your questions since you don't seem very appreciative.

Comment: Pooya - I appreciate the response :)  I'm new to QML so to me "TreeView.view" is very different from "myTreeViewID.view" (if that is what you are referring to).  I found in some cases I actually have to use the class name "TreeView.view" (which is confusing to me).